# Initializing more than one instance object at a time in init method

Tags: object-oriented, swift, ios

I have a `RadioStation` class file and a view controller where I create two station objects based on this class, one for FM and one for AM.

I created both of these station objects from within the same `required init` method. I'm not sure this was this the best way to do this, for example can you imagine if you wanted 8 such objects, this would just get very clunky. Is the issue rather that I am creating them in the view controller, and should I have in fact created separate subclass files for each and init them in those? 
Or should I have created two separate `init` methods, one for each new object?

RadioStation Class File: RadioStation.swift

```
import UIKit

class RadioStation: NSObject {

    var name: String
    var frequency: Double

    override init() {  //init class method to set default values.
        name = "Default"
        frequency = 100
    }

    static var minAMFFrequency: Double = 520.0
    static var maxAMFFrequency: Double = 1610.0
    static var minFMFFrequency: Double = 88.3
    static var maxFMFFrequency: Double = 107.9

    func isBandFM() -> Int {
        if frequency >= RadioStation.minFMFFrequency && frequency <= RadioStation.maxAMFFrequency {
            return 1 //FM
        } else {
            return 0 //AM
        }
    }

}
```

View Controller Class

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var stationName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stationFrequency: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stationBand: UILabel!

    var myStation: RadioStation

    var myStationAM: RadioStation //second object variable

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        myStation = RadioStation()
        myStationAM = RadioStation()
        myStation.frequency = 104.7
        myStationAM.frequency = 600.2
        myStation.name = "FM1"
        myStationAM.name = "AM1"
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        stationName.text = myStation.name //set top left label text to name property of myStation object instance
        stationFrequency.text = "\(myStation.frequency)"
        if myStation.isBandFM() == 1 {
            stationBand.text = "FM'"
        } else {
            stationBand.text = "AM"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonClickAM(_ sender: Any) {
        stationName.text = myStationAM.name
        stationFrequency.text = "\(myStationAM.frequency)"
        if myStationAM.isBandFM() == 1 {
            stationBand.text = "FM"
        } else {
            stationBand.text = "AM"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can someone tell me why this was downvoted? The code works, and I would like to learn about init methods for more than one object at a time. What did I do wrong?

Comment: One problem is that (on this site) the *title* should state what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it, compare [ask]. I would suggest to revise the title accordingly. Make it clear in the question the code works correctly.

Comment: (Cont.) There is one “Needs details or clarity” vote, so make sure that the code is self-contained, or at least contains sufficient context to understand it. Then you can (in the question, not in the title) describe your concerns about the code and what you would like to be reviewed. Make sure that it is not a “best practices” question as described in [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You are conceiving the band as being something derived from the frequency. While this may be technically correct, from a user perspective, you generally choose a band and then choose a frequency within that band. So, I might have a model that reflects this:

   ```
   typealias RadioFrequency = Decimal

   enum RadioBand {
       case am
       case fm
   }

   extension RadioBand {
       var allowedRange: ClosedRange<RadioFrequency> {
           switch self {
           case .am: return 520.0 ... 1610.0
           case .fm: return 88.3 ... 107.9
           }
       }
   }

   struct RadioStation {
       let name: String
       let band: RadioBand
       let frequency: RadioFrequency

       init?(name: String, band: RadioBand, frequency: RadioFrequency) {
           guard band.allowedRange ~= frequency else { return nil }

           self.name = name
           self.band = band
           self.frequency = frequency
       }
   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   guard let station = RadioStation(name: "KPCC", band: .fm, frequency: 89.3) else {
       // handle error here

       return
   }
   ```
2. If you really wanted to compute the band from the frequency, you could do:

   ```
   enum RadioBand: CaseIterable {
       case am
       case fm
   }

   extension RadioBand {
       var allowedRange: ClosedRange<RadioFrequency> {
           switch self {
           case .am: return 520.0 ... 1610.0
           case .fm: return 88.3 ... 107.9
           }
       }

       static func band(for frequency: RadioFrequency) -> RadioBand? {
           RadioBand.allCases.first { $0.allowedRange ~= frequency }
       }
   }

   struct RadioStation {
       let name: String
       let frequency: RadioFrequency
       var band: RadioBand? { RadioBand.band(for: frequency) }

       init?(name: String, frequency: RadioFrequency) {
           guard RadioBand.band(for: frequency) != nil else { return nil }

           self.name = name
           self.frequency = frequency
       }
   }
   ```
3. Minor details in the above:

   - I wouldn’t generally subclass `NSObject` unless there was a compelling reason to do so.
   - Whether you make it a `class` or `struct` is up to you, but we often we would lean towards value types and immutable properties unless otherwise needed.
   - I’m abstracting the frequency ranges for bands out of the `RadioStation` type. This is behavior of radio bands, not of individual radio stations, themselves.
   - The radio bands might be better represented as an enumeration rather than an integer that has only two values, either `0` or `1`.

     In general, if you find yourself inserting comments to explain cryptic values (e.g. where you note that `1` represents “FM”), that’s a good sign that you should adopt an enumeration, which makes its intent clear.
   - Note, I made `RadioFrequency` to be `Decimal`, rather than `Double`. I did that because you really don’t need floating point math, but rather want to accurately represent decimal numbers.

     FWIW, `Double` can introduce some strange behavior. Let’s say that you started at the lower bound of your AM frequencies and bumped it up by `0.1` ten times:

     ```
     var value: Double = 520.0
     for _ in 0 ..< 10 {
         value += 0.1
     }

     print(value, value == 521.0) // 521.0000000000002 false
     ```

     The result is not 521. But, if you use `Decimal`, you get the expected behavior:

     ```
     var value: Decimal = 520.0
     for _ in 0 ..< 10 {
         value += 0.1
     }

     print(value, value == 521.0) // 521 true
     ```

     See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).
   - I’d make the initializer failable in case the band didn’t match the frequency (or the band couldn’t be inferred from the supplied frequency).
   - I would not be inclined to have the `RadioStation` to have default values. That’s not a concept that makes sense. Sure, if you wanted your radio to default to a particular station, then fine, it would do that. But that’s not `RadioStation` behavior, but rather behavior of the radio.
4. You said:

   > ... imagine if you wanted 8 such objects, this would just get very clunky.

   If you had many, you might use collections. For example:

   ```
   let stations: [RadioStation]
   ```

   Or you might wrap it in a custom type that indicated the functional intent. For example, let’s imagine that your radio had programmable presets, then the model might be:

   ```
   struct RadioPresets {
       var stations: [RadioStation]
   }
   ```

   It just depends upon what these various stations are for. But don’t shy away from simpler fundamental object types just because you might need multiple ones. If the concept of a single radio station makes sense (which it does, IMHO), then stick with a simple radio station object, and compose it into more complex objects/models as needed later.

   But, as a generally programming principle, we generally prefer simple, cohesive types and compose complex objects from these simple objects (e.g. a collection of 8 radio stations).

Comment: Thank you again Rob, it's a lot to parse and will do so thoroughly, plus learn these new concepts.